# Add column to txt with conditional values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, twitter

I have a txt_file with lines such as this one:
"2017-03-21 12:00:00","844334879861069999","RT @__________: Ein wenig Zelda in der Schule spielen :) #SwitchMoment @NintendoDE URL"

I would like to add a column on the left with the values 4 for positive and 0 for negative depending on whether the line contains a positive (":)",":D") or negative smilie (":-(",":("). If both types are in a line, it needs to become a 99. I would be glad to hear any suggestions on how to achieve these results.
My try:

```
    import pandas as pd
    p_smilies=[":)",":D"]
    n_smilies=[":-(",":("]
    csv_input = pd.read_csv('input.csv')
    csv_input['sentiment']=0
    for line in csv_input["tweets"]:
            for p in p_smilies:
                    if p in line:
                            <ascribe value 4 to corresponding line in csv_input['sentiment]>
            for n in p_smilies:
                    if n in line:
                            <ascribe value 4 to corresponding line in csv_input['sentiment]>
<check whether both are in the same line and ascribe 99 to line>


    csv_input.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
csv_input = pd.DataFrame({'tweets': ['RT @_______len :) #SwitchMoment ', ':D :-( @NintendoDE URL', ':(', 'Ein wenig Zelda']})
print (csv_input)
                             tweets
0  RT @_______len :) #SwitchMoment 
1            :D :-( @NintendoDE URL
2                                :(
3                   Ein wenig Zelda
```

I add for no smiles new value `3`:

```
p_smilies=[r":\)",r":D"]
n_smilies=[r":-\(",r":\("]

mp = csv_input["tweets"].str.contains('|'.join(p_smilies))
mn = csv_input["tweets"].str.contains('|'.join(n_smilies))

csv_input['sentiment'] = np.where(mn & mp, 99, 
                         np.where(mn, 0, 
                         np.where(mp, 4, 3)))
print (csv_input)
                             tweets  sentiment
0  RT @_______len :) #SwitchMoment           4
1            :D :-( @NintendoDE URL         99
2                                :(          0
3                   Ein wenig Zelda          3
```

Or if same value `0` for negative and no smiles:

```
csv_input['sentiment'] = np.where(mn & mp, 99, 
                         np.where(mp, 4, 0))
print (csv_input)
                             tweets  sentiment
0  RT @_______len :) #SwitchMoment           4
1            :D :-( @NintendoDE URL         99
2                                :(          0
3                   Ein wenig Zelda          0
```